# Local variable "i" is accessed within an inner class fix?

Tags: java, actionlistener

I've seen some posts on this before, but I haven't been able to find one regarding actionListeners. I am trying to create tic-tac-toe using an array of JButtons. How do I add an action listener to them whilst using a for loop temporary variable if at all possible? Thanks for your help in advance.

```
JButton jb [] = new JButton[9];
int checkB [] = new int[9];
public SomethingSimple(){
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
   p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3, 5, 5));
   p1.setBackground(Color.red);
  for (int i = 0; i < jb.length; i++){
    checkB[i] = 0;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < jb.length; i++){
      jb[i] = new JButton("");
      p1.add(jb[i]);
      jb[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
           @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
              jb[i].setText("O");
          }
      });
  }
  add(p1);
 }
```

Thanks everyone for your help, you gave me some solutions!

Comment: Make it final. The fact that it's an `ActionListener` doesn't make any difference to the answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Anonymous inner class using a local variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251018/java-anonymous-inner-class-using-a-local-variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a final int inside the forloop; You cant access a local variable from your class to a anonymous class..

solution:

```
     for (int i = 0; i < jb.length; i++){
          jb[i] = new JButton("");
          final int index = i;
          jb[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
               @Override
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                  jb[index].setText("O");
              }
          });
          p1.add(jb[i]);

      }
```

Comment: I tried something similar, but it told me I couldn't change a final variable. I can't remember exactly what I did. Well I know now that I can do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution will be to move `ActionListener` to a separate class:

```
public class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
    private final JButton button;

    public MyActionListener(JButton button) {
        this.button = button;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        button.setText("O");
    }        
}
```

And change your code like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jb.length; i++) {
    jb[i] = new JButton("");
    p1.add(jb[i]);
    jb[i].addActionListener(new MyActionLisener(jb[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Local and anonymous classes can only access `final` local variables, so do something like

```
final JButton btn = jb[i];
```

inside the `for` loop immediately after you create the `new JButton` and then you can refer to `btn` inside `actionPerformed`.

Comment: He still wants to use the iterator, though.

Comment: @Human I meant inside the for loop, I suppose it wasn't particularly clear the way I first wrote it.

Comment: Oh, okay, that makes sense. Will `btn` still refer to the same object that `jb[i]` does?

Answer (score 0):

This is coming from a C# programmer, who is 15, so take it with a grain of salt. First as I understand your question, you want to add the `actionListener` to all of your Jbuttons in the array `jb`, with a for loop. 
Basically in my java experience, you'll have to implement `actionListener` into your class(or into whatever class that'll act as the actual listener). Then your code should look something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < jb.length(); i++)
{
  jb[i].addActionListener(class that implements the listener);
}
```

Please tell me if I misunderstood your question.