# Error: local variable imagesLabel is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final (Java)

Tags: java, final

#### Background

On following screenshot, the user should be able to change the image by clicking on one of the radio buttons:

[image: screenshot]

When a radio button is clicked the picture should change to a different one .
I have put all images into an array.

#### Problem

When compiling code I have tried so far (see source below) the compiler gives following error:

> Error: local variable `imagesLabel` is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final

And once I add `final` before respective variable, I got following error when compiling:

> Error: <identifier> expected

#### Java Code (after adding the `final`)

```
Icon[] images = new Icon[3];

// Get the images and store them in the images array.  These images 
// were manually resized to be similar in size prior to writing the
// program.
images[0] = new ImageIcon("/Users/grimygod/Desktop/negativeFilterExample.png");
images[1] = new ImageIcon("/Users/grimygod/Desktop/reflect.png");
images[2] = new ImageIcon("/Users/grimygod/Desktop/colorSubtraction.png");

// The images will be displayed as the image on a JLabel without text
JLabel imagesLabel = new JLabel();

// Set the initial image to be the negative filter, and add it to the panel,
// since the radio button for the negative filter is initially selected.
imagesLabel.setIcon(images[0]);
iconPanel.add(imagesLabel);
radioButtonPanel.add(iconPanel);

// Creation of "Select An Image & Apply Filter!" button
JButton selectButton = new JButton("Select An Image & Apply Filter!");
submitButtonPanel.add(selectButton);
radioButtonPanel.add(submitButtonPanel);

// Makes the whole window visible
testFrame.setVisible(true); 

// First button is selected when program is ran
button1.setSelected(true);

button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        final imagesLabel.setIcon(images[2]);   //  <<<<< ERROR in this line 
   }
});
```

Comment: It's the variable imagesLabel that must be declared final: `final JLabel imagesLabel = new JLabel();`. But you shouldn't have this error unless you use Java 7 or before. Why are you using such an old version of Java?

Comment: It's for my class at school, my teacher told us what to download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do any of the following to resolve the issue:

A. Declare `imagesLabel` as `final`

```
final JLabel imagesLabel = new JLabel();
```

B. Declare `imagesLabel` as an instance variable i.e. outside the method. In other words, declare it in the class itself.

Make sure to remove `final` from `final imagesLabel.setIcon(images[2]);` i.e. it should be simply `imagesLabel.setIcon(images[2]);`

Comment: I just tried that and it's still giving me an error that says "Error: local variable images is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final"

Comment: @sinafarheidar12 so do the same thing with images. Same error, same fix.

Comment: Okay, but now I'm getting an error saying "Error: non-static variable imagesLabel cannot be referenced from a static context". I tried writing it in public void main(String[] args), but it didn't work either

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks for helping me out guys!

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue A

You are defining an [*anonymous inner class*](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/inner-class/) of type `ActionListener` when adding the listener, see (1) in code below. Then you try to *access* the variable `imagesLabel` which is declared outside (of the inner class), see (2) in code below. Since this variable is declared **non-final**, you **cannot use it** within an *anonymous inner class* like this.

► Thus compiling failed with message:

> Error: local variable imagesLabel is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final

Code in state A (before `final` was added):

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { // (1)
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        imagesLabel.setIcon(images[1]);   //  (2) <<<<< ERROR in this line 
   }
});
```

#### Issue B

Trying to solve it you followed the instruction of the message and would like to "declare" the variable `imagesLabel` as `final` directly in this line - marked (3) in code below.

But the line (3) is **not the location of declaration** of variable `imagesLabel`, rather than a **method call** on this instance variable.

The compiler reads the source code line beginning with `final` and expects an *identifier* hereafter, but there was a *method call*.

► Thus compiling failed with message:

> Error: <identifier> expected

Code in state B (after `final` was added):

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        final imagesLabel.setIcon(images[1]);   //  (3) <<<<< ERROR in this line 
   }
});
```

**⚠ NOTE:** same compilation error and fix (as [commented by JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59147293/error-local-variable-imageslabel-is-accessed-from-within-inner-class-needs-to#comment104521182_59147501)) applies to variable `images` which is used as argument in the same line (3) above.

#### Solution

You have to use the modifier `final` where the variable `imagesLabel` (as well as `images` array) is declared. Then you can access it inside the inner class like first in code state A:

```
final Icon[] images = new Icon[3]; // <<< here is the other declaration

/* ... lines of code left out for clarity  ... */

// The images will be displayed as the image on a JLabel without text
final JLabel imagesLabel = new JLabel(); // <<< here is the declaration

/* ... lines of code left out for clarity  ... */

button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { // (1) inner class
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        imagesLabel.setIcon(images[1]);   //  (2) <<<<< now you can use the final declared variable imagesLabel
   }
});
```

#### See also

- Q: [Java: Anonymous inner class using a local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251018/java-anonymous-inner-class-using-a-local-variable)
- Q: [Why a non-final “local” variable cannot be used inside an inner class, and instead a non-final field of the enclosing class can?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801829/why-a-non-final-local-variable-cannot-be-used-inside-an-inner-class-and-inste)
- Q: [Why are only final variables accessible in anonymous class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class)
- [Tutorial on Inner Classes](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/inner-class/)